# Chromecast Receiver URL on Wordpress Site?

Tags: android, wordpress, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to get the [Sample Media Player App](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample) working, and have run into a problem. I have whitelisted my two URLs, and have gotten the app to run on my Android device without any issues.

My problem starts when actually attempting to cast the sample media. My Chromecast correctly displays as an option, however choosing it from the list does not yield any results on the Chromecast, itself (although it appears that my Android device connects without any issues). Could this be caused by my whitelisted URL not ending in ".html"? Here (link removed) is my page, for what it's worth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the answer in this question ([Chrome-cast Sample App doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959825/chrome-cast-sample-app-doesnt-work)) can solve your problem.

Basically you need to set AppID in your receiver.html as well.

Comment: That worked, thanks for the link! I hadn't noticed that they had updated the receiver on sample app.

Comment: Oh, and I also renamed the "receiver.html" file to "development-page" (note the lack of the .html) in the app's receiver folder to match my site URL. I'm not sure if this actually made any difference, but thought it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: does the receiver url need to be an internet url?  I have registered site on my local lan machine something like http://<machine-name>/chromecast/rx.html. I have tested the access to the page too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider(mCastContext, this);

try to cheak its value, wheter it is returning true or false

if its returning false then it will not run properly