# Chrome-cast Sample App doesn't work

Tags: google-cast

I managed to whitelisted my device and I got the AppID and also setup my receiver url. 
I am able to build and run the CastSample App.
I can click the cast button and my TV shows a blank screen. 
I tried to select one media from the list but nothing is displayed on my TV.

From the log I see the follwoing error some seconds after I clicked the cast button. Am I missing anything?

```
07-30 20:29:12.895: W/StartSessionTask(19880): Expected a channel but never got a connection service URL
07-30 20:29:12.895: E/ApplicationSession(19880): StartSessionTask failed with error: failed to start application: no channel info received
07-30 20:29:12.900: E/CastSampleActivity(19880): onStartFailed failed to start application: no channel info received
07-30 20:39:58.690: V/CastSampleActivity(21776): Selecting Media
07-30 20:39:58.735: D/AbsListView(21776): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-30 20:40:03.890: V/MediaSelectionDialog(21776): Selected media: Big Buck Bunny
07-30 20:40:34.055: V/CastSampleActivity(21776): onStop called and callback removed
07-30 20:41:05.870: V/CastSampleActivity(21776): onStart called and callback added
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911939/unable-to-debug-whitelisted-device-applicationsession-failing-to-start if that isn't the cause of your issue, you'll probably need to share some code for us to assist.

Comment: I checked that and it solved my first problem with the following error: W/StartSessionTask(15590): StartApplicationRequest failed with status: -4 E/ApplicationSession(15590): StartSessionTask failed with error: failed to start application: request failed D/GameActivity(15590): start session failed: failed to start application: request failed

Answer (score 3):

I checked the cast-android-sample on github and find that they have updated the receiver.html to have:

```
// Initialize and start the media playing receiver
var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
    'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE', 
    [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE],
    "",
    5);
```

Then I put my AppID there and uploaded the new receiver.html to my server then restarted everything and now I am able to play these sample medias.